# Problema al enviar formulario dinamico jquery y ajax a php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

¡Hola a todos! vereís tengo un problema con el envio de información del formulario a php con ajax, ya que o solo consigo mandar "1" de los formularios o ninguno, y ya estoy medio loco buscando soluciones. He probado un monton de soluciones de la red, pero sigo sin enternder el motivo de por que no me recoge los datos.

Genero los formularios pulsado un botón, si se quieren meter más datos, se puede agregar los formularios necesarios.Los datos supuestamente los guardo en un array ya que se van a enviar varios datos con las mismas variables. Con ellos quiero recojerlos en fichero php y poder trabajar con ellos. El código que tengo actualmente es el siguiente:

Parte html y js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {
        var iCnt = 0;

// Crear un elemento div añadiendo estilos CSS
        var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
            padding: '5px', margin: '20px', width: '170px', border: '1px dashed',
            borderTopColor: '#999', borderBottomColor: '#999',
            borderLeftColor: '#999', borderRightColor: '#999'
        });

        $('#btAdd').click(function() {
            if (iCnt <= 29) {

                iCnt = iCnt + 1;

                // Añadir caja de texto.
                $(container).append('<label>Exclusión' + iCnt + ': </label><input type=text class="input" name="ex[]"" ' +
                            'value="" /><label>Operador: </label><input type="text" class="input" name="op[]"" ' +
                            'value="" /><label>Valor: </label><input type="text" class="input" name="va[]" ' +
                            'value="" /><label>I/O: </label><input type="text" class="input" name="io[]" ' +
                            'value="" /><label>Reglas creadas: </label><input type="text" class="input" name=cn ' +
                            'value=' + iCnt + ' readonly="readonly" /><hr>');
                if (iCnt == 1) {   

                    var divSubmit = $(document.createElement('div'));
                    $(divSubmit).append('<input type=button class="bt" onclick="GetTextValue()"' + 
                            'id=btSubmit value=Enviar />');

                }

        $('#main').after(container, divSubmit); 
            }
            else {//se establece un limite para añadir elementos, 30 es el limite

                $(container).append('<label>Limite Alcanzado</label>'); 
                $('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt-disable'); 
                $('#btAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            }
            //Envio de datos
            //var url = "prueba_datos.php";                                      
            $('#btSubmit').click(function() {
                var ex = $("input[name='ex[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
                var op = $("input[name='op[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
                var va = $("input[name='va[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
                var io = $("input[name='io[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
                $.post("prueba_datos.php", {
                    "ex":""+ex+"",
                    "op":""+op+"",
                    "va":""+va+"",
                    "io":""+io+"",
                }, function(data) {
                    if(data.res==1) {
                        alert(response.status);
                    }
                },'json');
                return false;
            });
        });

        $('#btRemoveAll').click(function() {// Elimina todos los elementos del contenedor

            $(container).empty(); 
            $(container).remove(); 
            $('#btSubmit').remove(); iCnt = 0; 
            $('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled'); 
            $('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt');

        });
    });

    // Obtiene los valores de los textbox al dar click en el boton "Enviar"
    var divValue, values = '';

    function GetTextValue() {

        $(divValue).empty(); 
        $(divValue).remove(); values = '';

        $('.input').each(function() {
            divValue = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
                padding:'5px', width:'100%'
            });
            values += this.value + ' '
        });

        $(divValue).append('<p><b>Tus valores añadidos:</b></p>' + values);
        $('body').append(divValue);



    }



</script>
<body>
<div id="main">
<input type="button" id="btAdd" value="Añadir regla" class="bt" />
<input type="button" id="btRemoveAll" value="Eliminar Todo" class="bt" /><br />
</div>
<div id="resp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Parte php:

```
$ex = $_POST['ex']; 
$op = $_POST['op']; 
$va = $_POST['va']; 
$io = $_POST['io']; 

var_dump($ex);
```

Comment: Verifica las comillas dobles `""` en esta parte -> `append('<input type=button class="bt" onclick="GetTextValue()"' + 
                            'id=btSubmit value=Enviar />');` le hacen falta a algunos atributos, tla vez eso te esté generando un error.

Comment: Comillas corregidas, sigue sin enviar nada. Perdona mi ignorancia, pero nose a que atributos más te refieres. Por cierto he añadido esto: $('#resp').html(data); dentro del if(data.res==1) de la funcion de envio de datos, para mostrar lo enviado en un div inferior, aunuqe no se si esto sea correcto, la verdad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El motivo es que en `prueba_datos.php` no estás recogiendo el array de datos que envías.
He probado tu código y modificando el archivo php  como te indico a continuación y los datos se reciben correctamente:

```
 <?php
  $data = [
  $ex=$_POST['ex'],
  $op=$_POST['op'],
  $va = $_POST['va'],
  $io = $_POST['io'],

  ];
   echo json_encode(['ex'=>$ex,'va'=>$va,'io'=>$io,'op'=>$op]);
```

Si haces un `var_dump($data)` obtienes esto:

```
 array(4) {
 [0]=>
 string(3) "3,4"
 [1]=>
 string(5) "33,44"
 [2]=>
 string(7) "333,444"
 [3]=>
 string(9) "3333,4444"
 }
```

espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ya tengo los cambios añadidos. Pero tengo una duda más. Se supone que si todo se envia correctamente me debería aparecer una alerta diciendo el status, cosa que no ocurre, además he añadido justo de bajo de esta alerta esto:   $('p').hmtl(data);   para mostrar los datos del php pero tampoco ocurre nada, no se si la llamada a estos datos no la hago correctamente, o es que no consigo enviar nada.

Comment: Solucionadas las mini dudas que añadí. Muchas gracias por todo.